# Adding a role to users that are registered through Facebook in Dotnetnuke

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke, roles

Is it possible to add a role on users after they register to my dotnetnuke site through facebook?

I'm using the out of the box version of the facebook login control located at `DesktopModules\AuthenticationServices\Facebook\Login.ascx` and after the login procedure is done I want to add a role to the created user.

Is this possible through settings? If not, is there a way to determine in code if the user is registered through facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in the standard FB provider for DNN. You likely would need to do this via the database, I would recommend looking at a user that you know was added through FB and see if you can see any differences in their profile from a regular user (likely in their username) and see if you can create a SQL trigger that handles that role addition.

Comment: Thanks Chris, this is exactly how I solved this problem. It´s achieved pretty simple by querying the UserAuthentication table and looking for a authenticationtoken for Facebook.